# Profile page not showing reputation grouped by post

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

Was taking a look at the 'reputation' tab in my profile page and noticed that when I click the 'post' tab it still shows my reputation points grouped by 'time'.

The 'graph' tab seems to be working fine.

Found this behavior in Stack Overflow and was able to reproduce it here in Meta Exchange also.

[image: 'time' tab]

[image]

Comment: Reproduced in [scifi.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still sorted by *date*, though. "Time" just means time within the day. So, if you're earning rep on 3 posts, it will sort all of those votes by the time they came in but if you sort by post it will combine all of the votes for each individual post for that day.  Here's an example using my profile:

Here's the sort by post for March 3rd.

[image: Sort by Post]

And here's the sort by time for March 3rd.

[image: Sort by Time]

As you can see, while the specific posts do get combined in the second view *if* the votes are consecutive, they don't get combined if they're interleaved with other posts getting/losing reputation.

In the examples you've posted, there's only one item on the day, so there's no change to be seen. I admit that it's somewhat unclear but I'm pretty sure this is by design.

We sort voting by day as it relates to the reputation cap, so we want to know what reputation was earned on a specific day and then we allow you to sort the reputation changes for that day however you wish.

Comment: Looking at my Stack Overflow profile (which I have more activity) I can see that this is the behavior indeed. I just feel that the communication is a little confuse. Expected to see a list of my posts with the activity for each one of them sorted by date.